# dial-http tcp 127.0.0.1:51640: unexpected EOF

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-machine

Docker version -> 18.09.0, build 4d60db4

`docker-machine version -> 0.16.0, build 702c267`

After running docker-machine create -D --driver virtualbox default

I get the following:

```
Found binary path at /usr/local/bin/docker-machine
Launching plugin server for driver virtualbox
Plugin server listening at address 127.0.0.1:51640
dial-http tcp 127.0.0.1:51640: unexpected EOF
```

the server gets disconnected/destroyed after this.

Comment: I get it on minishift start. Something to do with port being blocked?

Comment: I think all ports are exposed :/ how can I check?

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar error while starting minishift on my machine. Turned out that we had some sort of corporate policy being forced on the machine using bluecoat. Disabling it made my error go away. Not sure if that is your issue.

Comment: something similar was happening. I had to whitelist the servers in AWS and it all got solved :) thanks for the reply